# Script to get the azure function key and put it in keyvault using azure powershell inline task in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, azure-powershell, paas

I have ran this below commands in azure PowerShell inline script task with 3.1.0 version in Azure DevOps.

```
$accountInfo = az account show

$accountInfoObject = $accountInfo | ConvertFrom-Json

$subscriptionId  = $accountInfoObject.id

$resourceGroup = "BZE1ERG01"

$functionName = "BAZE1EFA01"

$functionkeylist = az rest --method post --uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$functionName/host/default/listKeys?api-version=2018-11-01"

$keylistobject = $functionkeylist | ConvertFrom-Json
$functionKey = $keylistobject.functionKeys.default    

$tmpSecret1 = ConvertTo-SecureString $functionKey -AsPlainText -Force

Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'azu-qa-keyvault' -Name functionkeysecret -SecretValue $tmpSecret1
```

DevOps screenshot

[image]

I am getting an error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above error `Please run 'az login' to setup account` occurred is because you were running azure cli commands (eg.  `az account show`) inside azure powershell task.

- Azure powershell task is only authorized to run [azure powershell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-3.8.0).
- And Azure CLI task is only authorized to run [azure cli commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest).

So if you want to run azure cli commands inside Azure powershell task. You will need to run `az login` to login. eg. `az login --service-principal -u <app-url> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>`. If you donot have a service principal. You can follow the detailed steps in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key).

Please check Document [Sign in with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) for more information.

**Update: Use powershell to call Azure rest API.**

You can use `Invoke-RestMethod` to make Azure rest API call. You will still need to provide authentication for the API calls. You can refer to below example from [this blog](https://azsec.azurewebsites.net/2019/12/20/a-few-ways-to-acquire-azure-access-token-with-scripting-languages/).

```
function Get-AccessToken {
    $context = Get-AzContext
    $profile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
    $profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($profile)
    $token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($context.Subscription.TenantId)
    return $token.AccessToken
}
$subscriptionid = "subscriptionid"
$rg_name = "off-rg"
$rm_endpoint = "https://management.azure.com"
$authHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + (Get-AccessToken)
}

$uri = "$rm_endpoint/subscriptions/$subscriptionid/resourceGroups/$rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2019-03-01"

$respone = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $authHeader -Uri $uri
```

You can also check out blog [Access Azure REST API using PowerShell](https://blog.tekspace.io/access-azure-rest-api-using-powershell/) for more information.

Comment: I need to use the azure powershell task only is there any other command in place of az account show is for CLI similarily any command in azure powershell.

Comment: I have ran this command in azure poweshell still same error plz run 'az login ' to setup account.

$accountInfo = Get-AzSubscription
$subscriptionId  = $accountInfo.Id
$resourceGroup = "BTAZE1EBISNRG01"
$functionName = "BTAZE1IBISNFA01"
$functionkeylist = az rest --method post --uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$functionName/host/default/listKeys?api-version=2018-11-01"
$keylistobject = $functionkeylist | ConvertFrom-Json
$functionKey = $keylistobject.functionKeys.default

Comment: Hi @Anujgupta `az rest ` is azure cli command. You have to run az login first in azure powershell task.

Comment: Hi this I got so I done some changes to run this commans in Azure powershell task.
$a= Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "Cloud Non-Production"
$subscriptionId  = $a.Id
but issue is coming in this command
$functionkeylist = azure rest --method post --uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$functionName/host/default/listKeys?api-version=2018-11-01"
Do you have any other command below one in az cli same command i needed for azure powershell.

Comment: Hi @Anujgupta You can use Invoke-RestMethod to make Azure rest API call in azure powershell. Please check above update.

Comment: Hi @Levi I changed some line 
$endpoint = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$functionName/host/default/listKeys?api-version=2018-11-01"
$headers = @{}

$functionkeylist =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $endpoint -Method Get -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'
 Now error comes - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: Hi @Levi I need one more help 
$objectid = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "BZE1EBISNRG01" -Name "BZE1IBISNDF03").Identity.PrincipalId
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy –VaultName "BZE1EBISNKV01" -PermissionsToKeys get,list -PermissionsToSecrets get,list -ObjectId $objectid
This script is running fine in cloudshell but getting error in azure dveops powershell task
2020-04-27T11:14:51.9495703Z ##[error]Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because it looks that you call using `az cli` is not authenticated. Following [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts):

> Use this task to run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment.
>   The Azure context is authenticated with the provided Azure Resource
>   Manager service connection.

You should use plain PowerShell Az module or if you want to use az li please consider using [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) which will take care of autorization. You can use `az keyvault secret set` to create/update a secret in KeyVault. Please take a look on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-set) for more details. Of course all powershell code is valid in this task.

It looks that authentication for one doesn't applu for the other. You can also login to az cli from your task with following syntax:

```
az login --service-principal --username <app-id> --password <password> --tenant <tenant-id>
```