# How can i use DataProtectionProvider to encrypt and validate user details?

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to create a function app in Azure that will accept some input data , for example email, userid and companyid.
With ths i then pass it to another service which will verify if the user is valid and if valid then they will be given a Json string back with some extar data in it , like expiry date.

Now I have other function apps in Azure which have multiple App keys and these keys are cycled every 30mins.
So I use the key to encrypt the Json string received above pass it to a client and then need to decrypt, but if the key is cycled I cant decrypt.
Is there something that can explain best practices for this and maybe using the blob storage and store keys in Key Vault and retrieve these keys to decrypt the json , does DataProtectionProvider provide this functionality ?

An example would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By using the `DataProtectionProvider` class to encrypt and validate user details. The `DataProtectionProvider` is a part of the .NET Core Data Protection API, which provides a flexible and extensible framework for `encrypting` and `decrypting` data.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection
```

AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions NuGet has to be installed.

[image]

The below is the code to be used.

```
public class UserDataProtection
    {
        private readonly IDataProtector _protector;

        public UserDataProtection(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
        {
            _protector = provider.CreateProtector("user-data-encryption-key");
        }

        public string ProtectUserData(string userData)
        {
            byte[] protectedData = _protector.Protect(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userData));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(protectedData);
        }

        public string UnprotectUserData(string protectedUserData)
        {
            byte[] protectedData = Convert.FromBase64String(protectedUserData);
            byte[] userData = _protector.Unprotect(protectedData);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(userData);
        }
    }
```

Create a `UserDataProtection` class that takes an instance of the `IDataProtectionProvider` interface in its constructor.

And then use this provider to create a data protector by calling the `CreateProtector` method with a unique key identifier (in this case, "user-data-encryption-key").

And use the Protect method of the data protector to encrypt user data and the Unprotect method to decrypt it.

> Note that first convert the user data to bytes before encrypting it, and then convert the decrypted bytes back to a string after decryption.

To store the encryption key securely, you can use `Azure Key Vault`.

You can use the `UserDataProtection` class to encrypt and decrypt user data using the `DataProtectionProvider` instance.

For further information, refer the below MSDocs

[Data-protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/non-di-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Thanks to `Tamra Myers` for the  [Storage-service-encryption doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-service-encryption.md)

Comment: I assume i can put this in an Azure function app ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it by creating a function app using Visual Studio and use the code in your own class file and deploy it in azure after successfully build.

Comment: Also how can i get the most recent System keys for the function app ? would that be the user-data-encryption-key ?

Comment: To get the most recent system keys for a function app in Azure, you can use the Azure Management API or Azure PowerShell cmdlets to retrieve the function app keys. The system keys include the host keys and the system-assigned managed identity keys. You can check this [SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61341470/script-to-get-the-azure-function-key-and-put-it-in-keyvault-using-azure-powershe)

Comment: sorry  im new to al this stuff, but cant it be retrieved via c# code within the function app itself ?

Comment: To retrieve user data encryption keys in C#, you can use the Azure Key Vault SDK.

Comment: string keyVaultUrl = "<key-vault-url>";
            string keyName = "<key-name>";
            var keyClient = new KeyClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            KeyVaultKey key = await keyClient.GetKeyAsync(keyName);var cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(key.Id, new DefaultAzureCredential());         
            KeyOperationResult result = await cryptoClient.UnwrapKeyAsync(key.KeyType, key.Key.N);            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(result.Key).Replace("-", ""));

Comment: so in looking at this , does the System keys sit in a Azure Key Vault ?

Comment: Yes, Azure Key Vault is designed to store cryptographic keys and secrets that cloud applications and services use.